# finding multiple ocurrences of a string

Tags: c++

How can I find multiple occurrences of a string within a string? 
And replace the found string with another string in all occurrences? 
Say, I have the string below:

```
"A cat is going. It is black-white stripped."
```

I want to replace all occurrences of "is" with are.

Comment: I hope the cat is just "striped".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

string.`replace()` is what you want. Check it out [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/). Of course, that will have to be run multiple times, until the string you want replaced returns `string::npos` on a `find()`.  Try this out:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  if(argc != 3) {
    cout << "Usage: <binary> <toFind> <toReplace>" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  //string str(argv[1]);
  string str = "A cat is going. It is black-white striped.";
  string dest;
  string toFind(argv[1]);
  string toReplace(argv[2]);

  cout << "Original string = " << str << endl;

  while(str.find(argv[1]) != string::npos) {
    size_t pos = str.find(argv[1]);
    str.replace(pos, toFind.length(), toReplace, 0, toReplace.length());
  }

  cout << "Replaced string = " << str << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, there are a lot of error-checks that still need to be incorporated into this program. Say, for instance:

1. str is hard-coded. Not good.
2. Checks are not made to ensure that the length of the string to be replaced is not larger than str itself.

HTH,
Sriram.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Boost::String. IIRC, they have a find_all/replace_all function to do this. [Detail here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/string_algo.html)

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

int main() 
{ 
  std::string s = "A cat is going. It is black-white stripped."; 
  std::cout << boost::algorithm::replace_all_copy(s, "is", "are") << std::endl; 
}
```